# Numpy broadcasting bitwise union upon no bitwise intersection

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bitwise-operators, array-broadcasting

I am writing an algorithm that has a common scenario.  I have two large arrays of integers.  Call them k and j (because thats what I called them in my test code).

I take each element of k, and I take it's union with each element of j, BUT ONLY IF the intersection of the two elements is zero.

Example:

```
j = np.zeros(3, dtype=int)
k = np.zeros(3, dtype=int)
k[0] = 2
k[1] = 6
k[2] = 10
j[0] = 2
j[1] = 8
j[2] = 1

for i in xrange(3):
    mask = (j&k[i] == 0)
    nextpart = (j|k[i])[mask]
    print i, nextpart
    print ""
```

> 0 [10  3]
>
> 1 [14  7]
>
> 2 [11]

### Question 1

Is this method actually efficient?  My algorithm is mostly based upon this operation right here, so it will make a large difference to know the best way to do this.

### Question 2

For every two arrays, I want to output all of the results into a single 1d array.  As we can see, with the method above, I am outputting to different arrays.  I imagine I can use some sort of concatenation method, but I also suspect based on the little I know about arrays that this might be relatively time consuming.  I could use some advice on how to accomplish this efficiently.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question 2 is a bit confusing. Anyway, you can do $ and | operations efficiently using broadcasting.

```
import numpy as np

j = np.zeros(3, dtype=int)
k = np.zeros(3, dtype=int)
k[0] = 2
k[1] = 6
k[2] = 10
j[0] = 2
j[1] = 8
j[2] = 1

# alter shape to broadcast
k_ = k[None].T
r = (j|k_)[j&k_==0]
print(r)
```

This results in

```
[10  3 14  7 11]
```